# How to show all the quizzes, student's scores and if they have taken the quiz from 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 4 tables:

```
Teacher: id, teacher

Student: id, student

Quiz: id, teacher_id, answer, dis_1, dis_2, dis_3

Intermediate: id, student_id, teacher_id, score
```

Teachers create quizzes and students take quizzes. The intermediate table keeps track of the scores on quizzes with the relevant IDs.

**I would like to return all the quizzes and indicate either the student's score or that they haven't taken it.**

If they haven't taken the quiz, then the Intermediate table will not have an entry for that student. If they have take the quiz, then the Intermediate table will have the score.

This is my statement so far:

```
SELECT Quiz.question as question, 
Quiz.id as id,  Quiz.title as title,
Quiz.teacher_id as teacher_id, Teacher.teacher as teacher, 
Quiz.answer as answer, Quiz.dis_1 as dis1, 
Quiz.dis_2 as dis2, Quiz.dis_3 as dis3,
Intermediate.score as score 
FROM Teacher, Intermediate 
RIGHT JOIN Quiz ON Quiz.id = Intermediate.quiz_id 
RIGHT JOIN Student ON Student.id = Intermediate.student_id 
WHERE Quiz.teacher_id = Teacher.id
```

When I try that statement I get all of the quizes taken and it displays the score for whoever just took it. I want it to just display the score if it exists in the Intermediate table.

Comment: when you try that statement, what happens?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Good first question.  It would help if you also told us what this query does and what isn't working the way you'd like.

Comment: added formatting for sql

Comment: When I try that statement I get all of the quizes taken and it displays the score for whoever just took it. I want it to just display the score if it exists in the Intermediate table

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be close.  One thing that may be causing you issues is:

```
FROM Teacher, Intermediate
```

When you combine tables without using the explicit `INNER/RIGHT/LEFT JOIN` syntax, it can often lead to undesired results, especially for outer joins.  You can read more about [MySQL JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) which may help as you move forward.

You also did not have the student's name in your select, which I added so you see the name of the person associated with the score.  If you have a student that has not taken a quiz, their name, and score, will be `NULL`, due to how a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` works (Returning all the rows from the left table, and matching rows or `NULL` for the right table)

```
SELECT q.question, q.id, q.title, q.teacher_id, t.teacher
   , q.answer, q.dis_1, q.dis_2, q.dis_3, s.student, i.score
FROM Quiz AS q
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Intermediate] AS i ON q.id = i.quiz_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Teacher AS t ON i.teacher_id = t.teacher_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Student AS s ON i.student_id = s.student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE Quiz.teacher_id = Teacher.id` this is converting your right joins into inner joins.

Also I find it difficult to reason about RIGHT JOINS so I've converted it to LEFT JOINS

```
SELECT
    Quiz.question as question, 
    Quiz.id as id,  Quiz.title as title,
    Quiz.teacher_id as teacher_id, Teacher.teacher as teacher, 
    Quiz.answer as answer, Quiz.dis_1 as dis1, 
    Quiz.dis_2 as dis2, Quiz.dis_3 as dis3,
    Intermediate.score as score 

FROM
  student
  LEFT JOIN Intermediate 
    ON  Student ON Student.id = Intermediate.student_id
  LEFT JOIN Quiz 
    ON Quiz.id = Intermediate.quiz_id
  LEFT JOIN Teacher
    ON Quiz.teacher_id = Teacher.id
```

You might also want to add something from Student so you don't end up with a bunch of nulls

You might also want to add a Case Statement like this to the select statement

```
CASE WHEN Intermediate.score is null then 'not taken' else 'taken' end IsTaken
```